# How to say "pay exact amount of money"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, conversation

If cashier tells you that:

> I don't have change. Could you "pay exact amount of money"?

How to say "to pay exact amount of money" in good English?

Answer (score 7):

The most common phrase is "exact change", so you could say **Exact change, please**. While "change" is usually applied to coins rather than bills when talking about currency, it is acceptable when talking about the return of excess given during a purchase, "Here's your change."

And it is not always applied politely. [This news story](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/montreal/woman-fined-219-for-not-paying-bus-fare-with-exact-change-1.1335654) tells of a Canadian woman who was fined $219 for not having exact change when riding a bus.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to say this. One would be:

> Please, can you pay the exact amount? I don't have any change.

**Related**: Sometimes, if low on change, a cashier might ask:

> Can you pay in small bills?

I've even seen signs that say SMALL BILLS APPRECIATED to indicate a cash box is running low on change.

Answer (score 1):

You might say, "Could you please pay the exact amount sir/ma'am, we're running low on change".

Answer (score 1):

I would just add "the"

> I don't have change. Could you pay *the* exact amount of money?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could say, "Would you care to use some change to pay the bill. We are currently out of small change".