# How to say that some amount of money equals the demanded amount?

Tags: phrase-usage, conversation

My question relates to this: [How to say "pay exact amount of money"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51887/how-to-say-pay-exact-amount-of-money)

Now my question is from the payers point of view, not the payee.

During my latest trip I literally said to the the bartender "It's exact". I was referring to the amount of money I gave him, which equaled the amount of money the bartender asked me to pay for the drinks. My girlfriend laughed with me for my supposedly broken English.

Was the phrase "It's exact" correct in this situation?

Comment: I think you mean your girlfriend *laughed **at** you*. But she's obviously easily-amused, since there's nothing wrong with saying ***It's exact*** in your context.

Comment: Well I looked up the diff between laughing with and laughing at and in this case I thought "with" was appropriate because obviously she is not intentionally mean towards me.

Comment: You can laugh at someone without being mean. We laugh at professional comedians doing amusing things, for example.

Comment: Consider the one and only instance in Google Books of [he laughed **with** me for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+laughed+with+me+for%22), where it's actually ***...for** an instant* (briefly), not *...for something I did*. Compare that to almost 2000 instances of [he laughed **at** me for (being foolish, whatever)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+laughed+at+me+for%22).

Comment: The bartenders I've dealt with would be less than pleased that no tip was included. That aside, other ways of saying it would be: *It's correct* or the *correct amount*; *It's the right amount*; and *It should be right/correct*.

Comment: @RonaldSole Where I live, it's not a habit or at least not standard behavior to include a tip. I guess it's the other way around in the US. Good alternatives you propose there btw.

Comment: Another option is to say, "I don't need change," although (at least in the US where tipping is customary) that often means, "I have given you more than you asked for but the remainder is the tip."

Comment: I am unclear why you had to say anything. And are you sure your girlfriend was laughing at your choice of words, rather than the fact that you said what you did? Grammatically what you said was OK.

Comment: I think that it's far more likely that your girlfrend laughed because of what you did, not what you said. I used to pay the exact amount when I was fifteen and only had enough money for one drink: it's not something that grown-ups do in a bar. If the barman has done something to upset you, you could pay the exact amount and say "Keep the change". But only if you don't want to go back to that bar again.

Comment: Again, it's very common here to pay with a bill and get back the change without the servant expecting a tip from you. Not socially awkward at all, even for adults. Let's not overanalyse the situation here... The question was just about the choice of words...

Comment: @user3169 choice of words isn't the same as grammatical correctness.  If he'd said "it's a giraffe," it would have been grammatically correct but entirely unsurprising if someone had laughed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it was trivially obvious that the money was exactly the amount demanded (for example if you handed over a single coin of the right denomination), it might be polite/cautious to precede your words with "I think" or "I hope".

In British English the common phrase would be something like "I think that's the right money".

"It's exact" has slightly pedantic sound to my ears.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, if I wanted to tell the bartender that I'm giving him the exact amount of money he asked for, I would say something like:

- I have exact change (said *before* I hand the money over)
- Here's exact change (said *as* I hand the money over)
- I've got exact change here
- Here, I've got exact change for you

In practice, I wouldn't say *anything*, because the bartender is going to count the money that I gave him and see for himself whether it's exact change or not.